# Downloading one application when user tries to download other application

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-service

How to install facebook messenger when the user tries to install my application.

For example when user download facebook application on android it even downlaods facebook messenger. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch an intent to open the Play Store app with the package name of the app you want like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```